# Interface not showing up in airmon-ng

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running a virtual Kali machine on VirtualBox and want to connect my USB WiFi adapter to said VM.
Here are some details:

**Host OS**: Windows 8.1
**Guest OS**: Kali Linux 1.1.0a (amd64)
**USB Adapter**: TP-Link TL-WN725N

The adapter works perfectly during normal use in the VM and the iwconfig is as follows:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

However, the device fails to show up in airmon-ng:

```
Interface   Chipset     Driver
```

And running airmon-ng start wlan0 returns: (killing the processes didn't do any good)

```
Found 3 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after a short per
iod of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e

PID  Name
2188 dhclient
2275 NetworkManager
2809 wpa_supplicant


Interface    Chipset   Driver
```

And airodump-ng returns:

```
nl80211 not found
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or does the adapter simply not support monitor mode?
Or do I need some drivers to get this working?

Comment: im not very skilled about that but i think you should set your wireless device as monitor mode?

Comment: @FranciscoTapia I tried that and have edited question accordingly..

Comment: Can you please try `iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor`? What's the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
airmon-ng
```

And make note of your interface name, for example `wlan0`. Then type:

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

Then start monitoring mode:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Now run `airmon-ng` once again and note the new name of interface which will be something like this: `wlan0mon`

Now run airodump-ng with interface name as well:

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

Comment: As I've already said in the question, the device fails to show up when issuing these commands, any ideas to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when I wasn't connected to the internet. I think that if you get connected to the internet some way and then run the command, it will work.